# MYSQL Operação de subtração campos da mesma tabela com WHERE diferente?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-select

Olá

Existe uma tabela com campo TIPO e Valor,

Preciso do resultado do campo valor da operação (TIPO = RECEITA) - (TIPO = DESPESA) no MYSQL
em um Select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Precisa somar tudo que receita e subtrair tudo que é despesa? Ou há outras condições?

Comment: exatamente, somar tudo que é receita e subtrair tudo que é despesa, apenas.

Comment: neste caso, parece que já há uma resposta correta. se ela resolver o seu problema vc deve aceitá-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo para teste onde é utilizado o comando Case dentro da função Sum para multiplicar o valor por -1 quando o tipo for despesa, e dessa forma fazer a subtração:

```
select sum(valor * case when tipo = 'RECEITA' then 1 else -1 end) as resultado
from Tabela
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito Obg, Deu certo !